# Firefox some images do not show but they are correctly loaded if looking at firebug

Tags: firefox, firebug

I have some images that are not visible other are (background images or img tags indifferently ) If I check in firebug everything is fine, the image appears. It is as if they were a display:none applied to certain images while other are perfectly ok. In Safari/Chrome everything is just perfect.

Does any one has met this problem already?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe there is a problem in FF/Mac with BG images in a transparent BG? ... More likely, there is something about the page layout that renders that element underneath other content. ... Post a link to the page if you can.

Comment: I cannot yet post a link. On the other hand If I put the image in a <img> it does not show up as well. It is as if the tag has a display:none; ...

Comment: @Brock Adams how to PM I can give you an access to the dev server, I would just not like to have it displayed here ;)

Comment: Can you save the page to a file and then copy that source to [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/)?  There is no PM system here, so any email addresses, etc. we swap are visible to all.

Comment: Can you send an email to this one: sicicrai@temporaryemail.net it is temporary I will then send you my email adress.

Comment: You can "delete" comments, but they don't go away. Moderators can still see them.  Not sure if they are allowing 10K user to, yet. (You can check meta.)

Comment: hey, have you resolved this problem already?

Comment: AdBlock Plus also blocks images on StackOverflow. You have to add an exception for images in 'sprites' folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brock Adams has helped me out. That was an issue with AdBlockPlus. The pin image not displaying is called Ads_pin_big.png and in ABP there is a rule blocking images starting with /images/ads_ ... So had Adams Brock advised me: "choose your image names wisely"

Answer (score 0):

This has to be a problem with your cache. Clean it out, reboot your machine. CTRL f5 on those images. Should help.

Comment: I have added two printscreens, the first shows where the image should be the second shows that the images is there in the code...